# Django proper use of select_related or prefetch_related on a ForeignKey

Tags: django, optimization, django-queryset, django-orm, django-select-related

I'm trying to figure out how to use `select_related` or `prefetch_related` to optimize a query from the other end of a foreign key. For example:

Say I have some models such as the following:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    product = models.ForeignKey("myapp.Product", related_name="product_images")
```

If I want to print all of the `ProductImage`, I have to iterate through all of the products and then, for each product, iterate through all of the product images.  However, this produces O(n * m) database queries.

```
for product in Product.objects.all():
    print product.product_images.all()
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to utilize `select_related` or `prefetch_related` to reduce this lookup to one or two queries.

As documented by Django, I can get `select_related` to work when I select `ProductImage`.  As you can see, adding the `select_related` creates a JOIN to the product table.

```
>>> ProductImage.objects.all().query.sql_with_params()
(u'SELECT "myapp_productimage"."id",  ...  FROM "myapp_productimage" .... 

>>> ProductImage.objects.select_related('product').query.sql_with_params()
(u'SELECT "myapp_productimage"."id", ...   FROM "myapp_productimage" LEFT OUTER JOIN ....
```

However, how do I accomplish the reverse? For example, how do I query all of the `Product`s and have it JOIN on the `ProductImage`s?  Doing something like the following doesn't seem to work.

```
Product.objects.select_related('product_images').query.sql_with_params()
```

Is something like this possible in Django?

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is exactly what `prefetch_related` does.

```
Product.objects.prefetch_related('product_images')
```

However, there's no point in using `query.sql_with_params()` to diagnose this: `prefetch_related` does *two* queries, and the second one won't show up there. You should use `django.db.connection.queries` to examine the queries that Django is making, or even better use the Django debug toolbar to show you.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel.  Also, good to know that the sql_with_params() isn't showing the full picture.  I'll try using the other methods that you suggest.

Answer (score 8):

`select_related` is used when you have a forward foreign-key relationship and `prefetch_related` should be used when there is a reverse foreign-key relationship.

Answer (score 5):

### [Quick Answer]

Just in more detail:

- Use `select_related` when you have a `*-to-one` relationship — `OneToOneField` and `Foreignkey` which is known as `many-to-one`
- Use `prefetch_related` when you have a `*-to-many` relationship — `ManyToManyField` and reverse `Foreignkey` which is known as `one-to-many`

---

[NOTE]:

- Do not forget to set `related_name=` parameter which is helpful in the reverse queries:

  `Product.objects.prefetch_related('product_images')`
- Otherwise, you have to use it as follows:

  `Product.objects.prefetch_related('productimage_set')`